# RxJava: BehaviorSubject of a particular type

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I'm trying to implement some kind of RxBus that allows to post events of specific type and listen to them depending on object class. I'm using BehaviorSubject to support sticky events (that can be posted even before subscription). And the sticky event should be kept for each type. Here is the code:

```
private final Subject<BaseEvent, BaseEvent> bus = new SerializedSubject<>(BehaviorSubject.create());

public <E extends BaseEvent> void post(E event) {
    bus.onNext(event);
}

public <E extends BaseEvent> Observable<E> observe(Class<E> eventClass) {
    return bus.asObservable().ofType(eventClass);
}
```

It works just fine with one type of event. But when there is more different events, and the last posted event is of different type than the one I'm subscribing for, it gets filtered by ofType(), because BehaviorSubject keeps only the last event not depending on type.

I was thinking of two solutions:

1. To create a map of subjects for each type, but there are problems with subtypes.
2. To use ReplaySubject and filter the events using ofType() and distinct(). But I can't find a way to differentiate between the events that were emitted before and after subscription.

What do you think, is there a way to make these solutions work or maybe I'm missing something and there is a better way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't want a Subject but a [Relay](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay).

I propose you a third solution: writing your own Relay (or Subject) implementation that will remember all the different events. You don't need to rewrite a Relay or Subject from scratch, you can rely on an existing implementation (here, PublishRelay):

```java
import com.jakewharton.rxrelay2.PublishRelay;
import com.jakewharton.rxrelay2.Relay;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import io.reactivex.Observer;

public class RxBus extends Relay<Object> {

    private PublishRelay<Object> concreteRelay = PublishRelay.create();
    private Map<Class, Object> stickyEvents = new HashMap<>();

     public <T> T getSticky(Class<T> type) {
         return (T)stickyEvents.get(type);
     }

    @Override
    public void accept(Object value) {
        stickyEvents.put(value.getClass(), value);
        concreteRelay.accept(value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasObservers() {
        return concreteRelay.hasObservers();
    }

    @Override
    protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super Object> observer) {
        concreteRelay.subscribeActual(observer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the idea of keeping sticky events separately from the main subject didn't occur to me.  :)